# Difference between quadratic forms obtained from a p.s.d matrix and its partition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quadratic-forms

Let $A$ be a $n\times n$ positive semi definite matrix, with real valued entries. Partition $A$ as
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
A_{1,1} & A_{1,2}\\
A_{2,1} & A_{2,2}
\end{pmatrix},
$$
where, $A_{1,1}$ is a $m\times m$ matrix. Let $\mathbf{x}\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Consider the difference,
$$
g(\mathbf{x}) \equiv \mathbf{x}^\prime \left[ A - \begin{pmatrix}
A_{1,1} & \mathbf{0}\\
\mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0}
\end{pmatrix}\right]\mathbf{x},
$$
where, $\mathbf{0}$ denotes a matrix with all entries equal to zero. I want to show, $g(\mathbf{x})\geq 0$, for all $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Is this true? Or, is it true only for symmetric and positive (semi)-definite $A$?

Comment: The condition holds if and only if $A_{1,2} = A_{2,1} = 0$ and $A_{2,2}$ is positive semidefinite.

Comment: I just checked it with a simple example, with $A$ being a 2x2 correlation matrix. Its obviously not true in general. Thanks for the hint.